# Formatting All the cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

Training column 1 is suppose to be green if its 18 months before Training column 5. I used conditional formatting and for some reason the last row will not cooperate. How do I fix this?

Training column 1 date
row 1: 2/1/2020 (turned green)
Training column 5 date
row 1: 8/1/2021

Training Column 1 date
row 2: 2/1/2019 (turned green)
Training Column 5 date
row 1: 8/1/2020

Training Column 1 date
row 3: 2/15/2019 (turned blue) why did it turn blue and not green?
Training Column 5 date
row 3:  8/15/2021

I used this formula for green
=G16<=Edate($K$16,-18)
formula for blue
=G16

note: G16 is training 1
          K16 is training 5

Its happening in the other cells too. 
Training column 2 is suppose to be green if its one year before Training column 5.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you use absolute references in the conditional formatting formula, all rows will compare to cell $K$16. If you want the dates to be compared to the date in the same row, you need to omit the $ sign in front of the row number.

With a cell in row 16 selected, the conditional format formula should be

```
=G16<=Edate($K16,-18)
```

Then, when the rule is applied to rows below or above, the cell reference will change to K17, K18, etc.